# How to get the type of setter property in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Define a type of an object that contains getter and setter with different types.
How to get the type of setter?

Define a type of an object that contains getter and setter with different types.

```js
type Foo = {
    get bar(): number;
    set bar(value: number | string);
}
```

When trying to get the type of the property, it can be only get the type of getter.

```js
type Bar = Foo["bar"]; // number
```

So how can I get the type of setter? Like `number | string` in the example above.

I've tried this but doesn't work.

```js
type SetterType<T, U extends string> = T extends { set [key in U]: infer P } ? P : never;
type Bar = SetterType<Foo, "bar">;
```

---

**Add uses:**

Suppose an API looks like this.

```js
const foo = addFoo(); // function addFoo returns type Foo.
foo.bar = 123;
foo.bar = "123"; // setter type works fine.
foo.baz = true;
// other properties...
```

I want to wrap this function to represent these properties through a literal object.

Internal implementation via `Object.assign`.

```js
function myAddFoo(properties: Partial<Foo>): Foo {
    const foo = addFoo();
    Object.assign(foo, properties);
    return foo;
}

const foo = myAddFoo({
    bar: "123", // Error, `bar` must be number | undefined.
    baz: true,
    // other properties...
});
```

`bar` property in the literal object cannot accept the setter type `number | string`.

So this function arguments must accept the type of the setter.

```js
type FooSetters = /* infer all setters type, like `{ bar: number | string }` */;
function myAddFoo(properties: Partial<Omit<Foo, keyof FooSetters> & FooSetters>): Foo
```

Comment: TS doesn't supporn different get/set types IIRC

Comment: I don't think that set type is observable in conditional types. Even if we ignore the problem of making an object type with dynamic setters, we can't get the type of the setter even for a fixed key: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ0PQOYFMAu0ARmAE4AUAlAFzQB2ArgLaE4krQn70m3QAM0AL7pMEfEVJkAbmBD0cNBs1bQAPtAh4SAS1pYK7YcNR4AngAcc0ABoAeACoA+aAF4M96DgAeeHLQAmMMga4sTkMnIK0LoAZioAqgaC0AD80PHQVLQ4UqwA3KgmFlYASq42tgjwzgD0NXRMLCSFQA

Comment: @Dimava they are supported in recent versions

Comment: See [this](https://tsplay.dev/wRzp1w). It will always return a `number`, because `bar` is a number, and `value` argument should be a number. It is not something you pass into the setter, it is grabbed automaticaly from the context

Answer (score 0):

A basic `Equal` can't compare the types, so you either can't do it or need a better equal

```
export type Equal<X, Y> =
  (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends
  (<T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2) ? true : false


type x6 = Equal<{
  // ^? true
  get bar(): 1;
  set bar(v: 1 | 2);
},{
  get bar(): 1;
  set bar(v: 1 | 2 | 3);
}>
```